# How do I append more record into existing .csv file

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to write .csv file using java.I am using SuperCSV jar.
I have a scenario that I have to write record into batch.
for an example If i have 100 record I have to write into same .csv in batches of ten.

1. First problem I am facing that its not giving me option to download
   the file or its not writing into csv file. I am just getting the
   value in console.
2. How do I achieve writing into batches.

**This is my java code**

```
 public class SuperCSVParserExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     //List<Employee> emps = readCSVToBean();
     Employee emp1=new Employee();
     Employee emp2=new Employee();
     Employee emp3=new Employee();
     Employee emp4=new Employee();
     Employee emp5=new Employee();
     emp1.setId("1");
     emp1.setName("A");
     emp1.setRole("Developer");
     emp1.setSalary("100000");

     emp2.setId("2");
     emp2.setName("B");
     emp2.setRole("Tester");
     emp2.setSalary("200000");

     emp3.setId("3");
     emp3.setName("C");
     emp3.setRole("Developer");
     emp3.setSalary("300000");

     emp4.setId("4");
     emp4.setName("D");
     emp4.setRole("Developer");
     emp4.setSalary("500000");

     emp5.setId("5");
     emp5.setName("E");
     emp5.setRole("Manager");
     emp5.setSalary("600000");

     List<Employee>emps=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        emps.add(emp1);
        emps.add(emp2);
        emps.add(emp3);
        emps.add(emp4);
        emps.add(emp5);
        System.out.println(emps);


        System.out.println(emps);
        System.out.println("******");
        writeCSVData(emps);
    }

    private static void writeCSVData(List<Employee> emps) throws IOException {
        ICsvBeanWriter beanWriter = null;
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try{
            beanWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/user/Desktop/employees.cs"),CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
            final String[] header = new String[]{"id","name","role","salary"};
            final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();

            // write the header
            beanWriter.writeHeader(header);

            //write the beans data
            for(Employee emp : emps){
                beanWriter.write(emp, header, processors);
            }
        }finally{
            if( beanWriter != null ) {
                beanWriter.close();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("CSV Data\n"+writer.toString());
    }

    private static List<Employee> readCSVToBean() throws IOException {
        ICsvBeanReader beanReader = null;
        List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        try {
            beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader("employees.csv"),
                    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

            // the name mapping provide the basis for bean setters 
            final String[] nameMapping = new String[]{"id","name","role","salary"};
            //just read the header, so that it don't get mapped to Employee object
            final String[] header = beanReader.getHeader(true);
            final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();

            Employee emp;

            while ((emp = beanReader.read(Employee.class, nameMapping,
                    processors)) != null) {
                emps.add(emp);
            }

        } finally {
            if (beanReader != null) {
                beanReader.close();
            }
        }
        return emps;
    }

    private static CellProcessor[] getProcessors() {

        final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] { 
                new UniqueHashCode(), // ID (must be unique)
                new NotNull(), // Name
                new Optional(), // Role
                new NotNull() // Salary
        };
        return processors;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried calling `flush()` before closeing the `beanWrtier`? And why do you expect the `System.out.println("CSV Data\n"+...)` to print any data?

Comment: Ok now its working, writing into the same csv file .. but how do i append into batches

Comment: What do you mean by batches? Why can't you just write all the information you have in one go?

Comment: @Soana I have already mentioned in question ..

Comment: But what you have mentioned is incomprehensible to me, so I would need some more explanation, before I could help you